# Where are the openCV #include files installed?

Tags: opencv, compilation, directory, include, g++

When compiling demo OpenCV code, such as,

`` g++ HoughLines_Demo.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` -o HoughLines_Demo ``,

the compiler cannot find the header files:

`HoughLines_Demo.cpp:7:33: fatal error: opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
                                 ^`

If I downloaded opencv-3.0.0 correctly, these header files *do* exist on my computer already, right? If so, what do I need to do to link them correctly?

The exact error message:

Running: 
Ubuntu 14.04,

g++-4.8,
4.8.4-2 ubuntu1~14.04

**Update:**

Looking up this problem more, the problem should be outdated OpenCV code. I ran `pkg-config --modversion opencv` which returned `2.4.8`. I could have *sworn* I was running 3.0.0 . What is going on here?

Comment: Is the header files directory within a search directory. Also not that it should matter but it might, what OS are you using? What version of gcc are you using? Finally, what are the specific error messages that it is giving you?

Comment: Added! Ubuntu 14.04, g++ 4.8.4, "No such file or directory." I do not understand what you mean by "within a search directory."

Comment: By "Within a search directory" I mean is it within the location that the compiler is searching? (In this case, it is likely installed under /usr/include) Also verify the tutorial's version, if I recall imgcodecs.hpp does not exist in opencv3.0.0, (It was in opencv 2.x.x)

Comment: Also in regards to the update, did you install from the ubuntu repository or build it yourself? Ubuntu's 14.04 has opencv 2.4.8 by default if I recall. (Been a month or so since I last checked, but I believe this is still accurate.)

Comment: I cannot determine where the folder is that the compiler is searching, but it is true that imgcodecs.hpp is the only one missing. However running `pkg-config --modversion opencv` returns 2.4.8, which implies I am running the right version. But today I tried installing 3.0.0. I am going to try restarting to see if that fixes anything... Nope, nothing changed.

Comment: So I believe Ubuntu did have OpenCV installed before, which may be where the 2.4.8 is coming from. So then the question becomes "How can I switch between the two?" Sources say that I would have to use 3.0.0 to use imgcodecs, because it is new.

Comment: You will need to uninstall your current opencv, download it from: http://opencv.org/downloads.html , and then build and install it onto your system.